# replacing single break tags for two using regex

Tags: php, regex

Whilst being aware of the pitfalls/dangers of certain html manipulation with regex (instead of using say the PHP dom manipulator) I'm trying to achieve something that should be pretty simple and not that risky.

Basically I have some uncleaned html copy from a database that doesn't use paragraphs but line break tags to produce the effects of paragraphs. Sometimes though the user only entered content with a single break so that the text line returns but without a blank line appearing. In such instances and ONLY in such instances I want to replace that single `<br>` with two (`<br><br>`).

So as an example...

```
This is <br>a test<br><br>example!
```

would become

```
This is <br><br>a test<br><br>example!
```

Note how the second set of breaks is left alone as its already got 2 tags.

Comment: A simple way would be to replace the double-breaks first, with a placeholder, then replace the single with double, then replace the placeholders with the doubles. If your text is consistent (no extra spaces or slashes, and no triple-breaks), then you can do this with simple string replacements instead of regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace one or more occurences of `<br>` with `<br>` :)

Replace what:

```
(<br>)+
```

Replace with:

```
<br><br>
```

Comment: OP only wants to do the replacement if there is a single <br> this will match any number such as <br><br><br><br>

Answer (score 3):

You can use [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to solve this:

```
(?<!<br>)<br>(?!<br>)
```

See the example here: http://rubular.com/r/WYjoenH1SA

```
(?<!NOPREFIX)
(?!NOPOSTFIX)
```

The first part prevents from matching, if the `NOPREFIX` is present - the second one if `NOPOSTFIX` is present.